React Native WebView iOS - iframe not showing on production / testflight build but evrything works locally
Iframe not showing in production build just white screen, but everything works locally. Just iOS on android works just fine. This is my WebView component:
 <WebView
          key={webViewKey}
          onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          onMessage={onMessage}
          ref={webviewRef}
          injectedJavaScript={INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT}
          onContentProcessDidTerminate={syntheticEvent => {
            const {nativeEvent} = syntheticEvent;
            webviewRef.current.reload();
          }}
          source={{
            uri: 
            webUrl || notificationUrl || url
          }}
          style={{flex: 1}}
          onLoadProgress={async ({nativeEvent}) => {
            setWebViewCanGoBack(nativeEvent.canGoBack);
          }}
          onLoad={handleWebViewLoad}
        />

"react-native": "0.72.4",
"react-native-webview": "^13.6.0",

Tried adding urls to originWhitelist. Nothing works, just white screen
